# XSLT multiple output files not working with namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon, docbook

Im trying to generate multiple html output files from one merged xml file with xslt 2.0

it works as expected when i have no namespace in the section

when i use the docbook namespace there are no files generated.

Does someone know why its not working with a namespace?

my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" name="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="book/chapter/section">
            <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('www/out/',@xml:id,'.html')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$filename" />  <!-- Creating  -->
            <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="html">
                <html><body>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </body></html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <chapter>
        <section xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"  xml:id="lorem_1" >
            <title>Lorem ipsum 1?</title>
        </section>
        <section xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xml:id="lorem_2" >
            <title>Lorem ipsum 2?</title>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

without

> xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"

it generates me 2 html files

im using **Saxon 9.1.0.8J from Saxonica**

build.sh

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/saxonb.jar

java net.sf.saxon.Transform -ext:on  -s:www/merged.xml -xsl:www/transform.xsl -T -xi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working with namespaces because you have not accounted for the namespace in your XSLT. You XSLT is looking for an element called `section` in no namespace, and so will not find the element in the XML which is in a namespace.

If, indeed, only the `section` and `title` elements are in a namespace, and not `book` and `chapter` too, you can handle the namespace by declaring it with a prefix in the XSLT like so:

```
xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
```

And then using that prefix wherever you need to select an element in that namespace:

```
<xsl:for-each select="book/chapter/db:section">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
        version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" name="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="book/chapter/db:section">
            <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('www/out/',@xml:id,'.html')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$filename" />  <!-- Creating  -->
            <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="html">
                <html><body>
                    <xsl:value-of select="db:title"/>
                </body></html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, supposing your XML had all the elements in the default namespace, like so:

```
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
    <chapter>
        <section xml:id="lorem_1" >
            <title>Lorem ipsum 1?</title>
        </section>
        <section xml:id="lorem_2" >
            <title>Lorem ipsum 2?</title>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

Then you could use `xpath-default-namespace` instead, to avoid having to use a prefix

```
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xpath-default-namespace="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
        version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" name="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="book/chapter/section">
            <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('www/out/',@xml:id,'.html')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$filename" />  <!-- Creating  -->
            <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="html">
                <html><body>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </body></html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```